# How to select particular divs using jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

How to alternate style (background color with jQuery) for `div` inside `div` with `id="container"` alternately (even and odd) if I have HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <span>10%</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>20%</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>30%</span>
</div>
.....
.....
```

How can I select the divs with above 50% and highlight them using jQuery?

Comment: please read the question completely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to answer your original question: http://jsfiddle.net/DRMZz/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var text = jQuery('span').text();

    var textArray = text.split('%');

    for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
        if((parseInt( textArray[i] )) > 50){
            var spanSelector = 'span:eq(' + i + ')';
            console.log(spanSelector);
            jQuery(spanSelector).css('background','yellow');
        }
    };
```

});​

Comment: can u give this using jquery selectors

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. This is all jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution for the :even, :odd selector, plus you'll have to cycle through the divs to get the 50%+ thing going

```
$('#container div').each(function(index, elem){
        if (index % 2 == 0) {/*even*/}
        else 
        {/*odd*/}
    if (parseInt($(elem).chlidren('span').text()) >= 50) {/*50%+ highlight*/}
        });
```

Comment: @Likwid_T You convinced me, but please note in your answer, is that alternative solution for simple :odd and :even selector.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#container > div:contains(50%)").nextAll().css({
    "background-color": "#FC0"
});
```

Selectors used:

- [Child Selector ("parent > child")](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)
- [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
- [jQuery.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

**Edit**: I am not really sure but perhaps you actually want this:

```
$("#container > div > span").filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var perc = parseInt(text, 10);
    return perc > 50;
}).css({
    "background-color": "#CF0"
});
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/hE5Ww/)

Comment: Search for "TheNewBoston" on Youtube. There is very good jQuery tutorial for beginners.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand... where is the div above 50% in your example markup?

Answer (score 2):

use the [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/), [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selectors

```
$("#container> div:even").css({'background-color':'Green'});
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4H44/19/)

---

to check if the div contains `50%` use the `contains` selector

```
$("#container> div:contains(50%):even").css({'background-color':'Green'});
```

## [*Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/C4H44/21/)

---

UPDATE: *the missing part*

```
$("#container> div").filter(function(){
  var val = $("span",this).text();
  var i = val.substring(0,2);
    console.log(i);
    if(i>50)return $(this);

}).filter(':even').css({'background-color':'Green'});
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4H44/33/)

Comment: u missed a part of the question..how can i select the divs with above 50% and highlight them using jquery...